# why does my combobox not have any values?

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I made a combobox htrough the ui then double clicked it to go to its VBA code.
Then I inserted this code.
I want to take the words from the columns D in worksheet 5 called "products" and insert it into the combobox.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim c As Range
ComboBox1.Clear
With Worksheets(5)
    For Each c In .Range(.Range("D5"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then ComboBox1.AddItem c.Value
    Next c
End With
End Sub
```

When i do this nohting happens. The combobox is just empty.

Update:
Trid this, its not working.

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim c As Range
With Worksheets(5)
    For Each c In .Range(.Range("D5"), .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        If c.Value <> vbNullString Then ComboBox1.AddItem c.Value
    Next c
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you doing that from the combobox change event? It will just keep triggering itself and clearing all the entries.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `vbscript` and not `VBA`?

Answer (score 0):

Double click in an empty space of your form and put your code there.
The reason it doesn't work is that you are populating the list when you are accessing it. You should populate it before you display your list.

Comment: Your second piece of code is working for me (although you might want to add `ComboBox1.Clear` after `Dim c As Range`). Does `Worksheets(5)` exist?

Comment: In your updated code you forgot to copy the line `ComboBox1.Clear`, as @CMArg mentioned. Also, I would not use `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, but `Worksheet_Change'. In that way, you are not refreshing the list every time you move in the sheet.

Comment: One more thing. In my response, I assumed that you are using UserForms. Or are you inserting it in the sheet? If you are inserting it into the sheet, then make sure that you are using ActiveX controls.